# JQuery does not work anymore when refresh the page SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, javascript, css

I want to change value of span by jquery (selecting by ID and CSS). The script works, but when I refresh the page, it does not work anymore.

I want to change the value 0 which CSS is **ms-comm-ratingCountContainer** with the value 2 which ID is equal to **ctl00_ctl43_g_7f25d3c9_92ec_46c7_96ef_9a9a6b6de7a7_DtList_ctl00_Label6**

How can I change this by JQuery ?

```
<div class="block">

<div class="sec-rating" id="ctl00_ctl43_g_7f25d3c9_92ec_46c7_96ef_9a9a6b6de7a7_DtList_ctl00_PnlRating">


  <span id="RatingsCtrl_ctl00_ctl43_g_7f25d3c9_92ec_46c7_96ef_9a9a6b6de7a7_DtList_ctl00_RatingControl">

    <div align="right" class="ms-comm-noWrap">

      <span id="averageRatingElement-51">...</span>

      <span class="ms-comm-ratingSeparator"></span>

      <span title="Nobody comments this." class="ms-comm-ratingCountContainer" id="averageRatingElement-51-count">0</span>
    </div>
  </span>
</div>

<span id="ctl00_ctl43_g_7f25d3c9_92ec_46c7_96ef_9a9a6b6de7a7_DtList_ctl00_Label6">2</span>

</div>
```

This is my jQuery, it works, but when I refresh the page, it doesn't work anymore, I must close the window and open a new one:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

var numItems = $('.sec-rating').length
var i = 0;

for (i = 0; i < numItems; i++){
var NumCount = $("span[id$='Label6']").text()[i];
$(".ms-comm-ratingCountContainer").eq(i).text(NumCount);
}

$("span[id$='Label6']").css("display","none");
});
</script>
```

Comment: could you please add the jquery code you are using

Comment: @Abhishek, Hi I add my jquery code

Comment: @Abhishek, Hi I found a solution, but when I refresh the page, it doesn't work anymore...........Could you have a look, please ?

Comment: I am assuming `sec-rating` is a wrapper div or something. I can't see a reason why this would not work after page refresh. I'll check and post an answer if I get anything